# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.OracleClient'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I am doing a .net core web application. However when I try to connect to sql server the following error message appears:

> Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException', "Could not load
>   file or assembly 'System.Data.OracleClient, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot
>   find the file specified."

Then I installed `System.Data.OracleClient` version 1.0.8(doesn't have 4.0.0.0?) using NuGet package manager but still get the error.
I also installed ODP.NET library from Oracle but still doesn't help.

Anyone can help with this?

Comment: You have to review your dependencies carefully, as that error message indicates possibly a .NET Framework based assembly linked to the old Oracle ADO.NET provider. Try to get rid of that .NET Framework dependency and the issue should disappear.

Comment: @LexLi Yes that probably the problem is. But if I have to use that assembly (no other assembly can replace it currently), is there any way to overcome this error?

Comment: If you really cannot go fully .NET Core, then ASP.NET Core 2.1 allows you to run on .NET Framework https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server#a-need-to-use-third-party-net-libraries-or-nuget-packages-not-available-for-net-core However, that approach has been deleted from later releases, so you won't find it a feasible alternative when 2.1 reaches end-of-life.

Answer (score -1):

`System.Data.OracleClient` was depricated. Don't use it for a new project. 
Install `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core` instead.

Also, `System.Data.OracleClient` was created for *.Net Framework*. It is not compitable with *.Net Core*. It is a real reason of the error. You can make a solution with *Asp.net Core* and *.Net Framework* together. It will be not cross-platform application. I advise you do not do it.

`Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core` is compitable with *.Net Core* (.Net Core 2 at this moment)

Comment: @LexLi, what do I have to add? Maybe, should I explain why does `System.Data.OracleClient`  not working for the TS`s project?

Comment: If you spend a minute on my comment above, you should see the problem did not start with the obsolete Oracle provider, so it won't end there either.